Mouse Movement and Clicks Not Working Correctly in Game Using YOLOv5 and PyWin32
I am working on an AI project to detect and shoot objects in the game Aimlabs using a YOLOv5 model. The code works fine when the game is paused, but it does not move the mouse accurately when the game is running, Got any ideas how to fix this?
import cv2
import torch
import numpy as np
import mss
from PIL import Image
import win32api
import win32con
import time

# Load the YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt')

# Set device (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device).eval()

# Screen capture settings
sct = mss.mss()
monitor = sct.monitors[1]

# Function to simulate mouse movement and click
def point_and_click(x, y):
    print(f"Moving to: ({x}, {y})")  # Debug
    # Move the mouse to the position
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, x * 65535 // win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0), y * 65535 // win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1))
    time.sleep(0.05)  # Brief pause before clicking to stabilize position
    # Perform the click
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    print(f"Clicked at: ({x}, {y})")  # Debug

while True:
    # Capture the screen
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
    img = Image.frombytes('RGB', sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, 'raw', 'BGRX')
    frame = np.array(img)

    # Perform inference
    results = model(frame)
    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]

    if not df.empty:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(row['xmin']), int(row['ymin']), int(row['xmax']), int(row['ymax'])
            conf, cls = row['confidence'], row['name']
            center_x = (x1 + x2) // 2
            center_y = (y1 + y2) // 2
            
            # Draw bounding box and label
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f"{cls} {conf:.2f}", (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            point_and_click(center_x, center_y)
    else:
        print("No objects detected.")

    cv2.imshow('YOLOv5 Object Detection', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

